# Can "Connection: close" header appear anywhere in headers?

Tags: apache, http, http-headers

Can "Connection: close" header appear anywhere in headers - or is that supposed to be the last header?

```
stan@stan-pc:~$ siege -g http://somesite.com/file.mp3
HEAD /file.mp3 HTTP/1.1
Host: somesite.com
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: 
User-Agent: JoeDog/1.00 [en] (X11; I; Siege 3.0.1)
Connection: close


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.8
Last-Modified: Sun, 08 Mar 2009 17:00:01 GMT
Content-Type: audio/mpeg
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Date: Thu, 21 Nov 2013 15:34:59 GMT
X-Varnish: 2281136124
Age: 0
Via: 1.1 varnish
Connection: close
X-Cache: MISS


stan@stan-pc:~$
```

Trying to troubleshoot mp3 files not being served.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can appear anywhere. Header field ordering in general is irrelevant.